# Visual Studio Code - при запуске live server не отображает на странице картинки

Tags: html5, visual-studio-code

На странице не отображаются изображения, путь до картинки указан правильно. При запуске index напрямую в браузере отображается,через live Server не отображаются.

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/WebDev/Project1/src/img/hroznys.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Путь к картинке должен быть указан относительный, а не абсолютный.